# How to handle exceptions for Mono.fromCompletionStage

Tags: java, project-reactor

I need to convert a CompletionStage returned by an external library into a Mono inside my reactive pipeline. How do i handle exceptions returned from the call (I want to ignore them and continue with the sequence)? The onErrorResume / doOn* operators are not getting invoked when the external call throws an exception (possibly because the Mono is never created because of the exception).

```java
private void example() {
    Flux.range(1, 2)
            .flatMap(i ->
                    Mono.fromCompletionStage(externalCall(i))
                            .doOnNext(ni -> System.out.println("onNext: " + ni))
                            .doOnError(err -> System.err.println("onError: " + err.getMessage()))
                            .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.empty())
            )
            .subscribe();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

CompletionStage<String> externalCall(int i) {
    if (new Random().nextBoolean()){
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception in external call");
    }

    return Mono.just(i)
            .map(e -> String.valueOf((char) (e + 64)))
            .toFuture();
}
```

Stack trace

```
2021-10-11T02:16:09,944 main r.c.p.Operators - Operator called default onErrorDropped
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in external call
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in external call
    at lrn.chap.SubscribingInFlatMap.externalCall(SubscribingInFlatMap.java:107)
    at lrn.chap.SubscribingInFlatMap.lambda$example$10(SubscribingInFlatMap.java:91)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:386)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRange$RangeSubscription.slowPath(FluxRange.java:156)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRange$RangeSubscription.request(FluxRange.java:111)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRange.subscribe(FluxRange.java:69)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8468)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribeWith(Flux.java:8641)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8438)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Mono.defer()` to convert it to a lazy publisher like this:

```
Mono.defer(() -> Mono.fromCompletionStage(externalCall(i)))
    .doOnNext(ni -> System.out.println("onNext: " + ni))
    .doOnError(err -> System.err.println("onError: " + err.getMessage()))
    .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.empty()))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `defer` method mentioned in the other answer is a good option but there is another shorter option which is using the lambda version of the `fromCompletionStage` method:

```java
Mono.fromCompletionStage(() -> externalCall(i))
    .doOnNext(ni -> System.out.println("onNext: " + ni))
    .doOnError(err -> System.err.println("onError: " + err.getMessage()))
    .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.empty()))
```

Just like `defer`, this will make sure that the `externalCall` method is called on-demand and errors are handled as part of the reactive chain.

Comment: I am really torn between accepting your answer Vs the other one (defer) since both are working fine. I am going to accept the Mono.defer() answer since i feel it makes the intent a bit more explicit. Thanks!